# expire a special session after some time in laravel

Tags: php, session, laravel, session-timeout

I have some admins for editing posts. I want ,when an admin is editing a post ,lock that post to prevent editing by other admins so I need a lock field from 0 to 1 and also I need to set lock_time for 30 minutes . because maybe that admin go out without click in "update" button . so I need set my lock field from 1 to 0 after 30 minutes again.

so for this I want to use session but I dont know how can I set a lifetime for a special session.because  lifetime field in session.php file is for all session but I want to expire just one.

thanks for time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me you can use a task, lock the post and create a task with cron, otherwise think different approach like this post [Prevent two users from editing the same data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792013/prevent-two-users-from-editing-the-same-data?rq=1)